# Making a text table with x amount of rows

Tags: python

I'm looking to make a text-based table in python. Its based on a competition where the user can select the number of rounds. As the rounds pass a score is added to a person for that round. I tried to make a table with columns for the person's name and the round. The problem is creating the columns for each round.

```
score_board = [["Charles",32,432,23],["Mathew",432,334,32]]
x = 2
print("|   Name   |"  + ("| Round 1 " )*x)
for item in score_board:
    print("|" + str(item[0]) + " "*(10-len(item[0]))+ "|" + str(item[1]) + " "*(10-len(str(item[1])))+ "|")
```

Comment: Just an advice, please try to avoid concatenating strings using `+`, there's already a `format()` function to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

as @NinjaWarrior said you need to use formats

```
score_board = [["Charles",32,432,23],["Mathew",432,334,32]]
round_number = 3
print("|   Name   "  + ''.join(["| Round %02d " % round_iter for round_iter in range(1,round_number+1)]))
for score in score_board:
    print( ''.join(['|%-10s' % item for item in map(str, score)]))
```

which gives

```
|   Name   | Round 01 | Round 02 | Round 03 
|Charles   |32        |432       |23        
|Mathew    |432       |334       |32
```

---

the `printf` format is described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting)

`"%s" % "robert"` outputs `"robert"`

`"|%s" % "robert"` outputs `"|robert"`

`"|%10s" % "robert"` pads s to the left to form a 10-length string: outputs `"|    robert"`

`"|%-10s" % "robert"` pads s to the right to form a 10-length string: outputs `"|robert    "`

it's the same logic for numbers:

`"%d" % 2` outputs 2

`"%02d" % 2` outputs 02

`"%03d" % 2` outputs 002

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I was wondering if you could explain it to me. Thx

Comment: i added some info on printf